Digging tunnels in a crossword?
The puzzle below seems like a normal crossword puzzle. However, there is an important thing to notice: The black squares aren't solid, it is possible to dig tunnels through them!

Rules + example
Let's say the answer to the first clue is "tunnel". You may then fill in this word in the crossword, by digging a tunnel through the black square after it and 'use' the space of a second clue at the other side of the square. A few things to note:

The word can split everywhere between the first 2 letters and the last 2 letters.
No letter should be put into the black square, the word continues at the other side.
This means that the second clue is not used anymore in the crossword. The second clue does not need to match the second part of the longer word. You could see this useless clue as a red herring, but maybe you'll need it for the final answer?...
The following tunnels are possible, all tunnels are starting at the left/top and coming out at the bottom/right.
There may be 2 tunnels in one black square, crossing each other.



If everything is clear, then let's continue with the actual puzzle!
The final answer is an appropriate movie quote.




Across
Down




1. Picture
1. Distinct style or character


5. The central part
2. Similarly


9. Seabird
3. Machinery


11. That is
4. Part of the head


13. A rich tapestry
5. Heard, understood, acknowledged


14. Common Era
6. Snow Queen


15. Function
7. Whiskey or vodka for example


17. Company that produces laptops
8. In that place


19. Blend
10. Restaurant


20. Nervous system disease
12. Part of a TV serie


22. Natural number
14. Focused (BrE)


23. Used to make conspicuous
16. Detonate


24. Sun
18. British English


25. Mistakes
20. Grasp


26. Article
21. Title


28. Deity
24. Greek letter


30. Beg
27. Something Jack Sparrow says


31. Someone who studies the earth
29. Cut of meat


32. Below
30. Tower of ...


35. Digital video
33. Drug


36. Fire
34. Alcoholic liquor


38. Alter
36. Minimum


39. Spruce
37. Emergency room




Would you care to clarify whether words can be split more than once?

I have purposely left out that part, that's something you have to figure out yourself :)

The filled grid:

 

The 'dummy' clues were:


 18d. British English
 20d. Grasp
 26a. Article
 36a. Below
 36d. Minimum
 37d. Emergency room

 And these can also be solved as clues: BE + HOLD + THE + UNDER + MIN + ER, or "Behold, the Underminer!", a quote from The Incredibles.

 Thanks to Stiv for helping me finish this off. 

The thematic quote you're looking for is ftom rot13(Gur Vaperqvoyrf - "Orubyq gur Haqrezvare!"). However, note these words do not necessarily match the grid word lengths.
